# fluid mechanics help

Tags: classical-mechanics

[image]

for part a) i get

$$  u = \partial_y \psi, \quad v  =  - \partial_x  \psi$$

I need help with part d, if anyone can show me how to? thanks

Comment: whoever edited this, thats not the equations i get, its meant to be  u = (partial psi) / (partial y) and v = - (partial psi)/(partial x)

Comment: Hello Italy, this is what you typed: "u = partial psi \ partial y, v = - partial psi/partial x", which I believe matches what I wrote, doesn't it? Furthermore, it's correct.

Comment: oh if its the same, than my bad! I have not seen it in this form before, but as long its the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Brute force* tells us that if $\psi_y = u$, then:

$$ \psi(x,y)  = \int u \, \mathrm{d}y + f(x) = \frac{x}{x^2+y^2} + f(x), $$ for some function $f$. Notice now that, on the other hand, if $\psi_x = -v$, then:

$$\psi(x,y) = - \int v \, \mathrm{d}x + g(y) = \frac{x}{x^2+y^2} + g(y), $$ for some function $g$. The computation of the integrals is left to you (check!).

What can we conclude about $f$ and $g$? Is there any obvious choice for them?

Cheers!

Comment: f and g must be the same constant? but this doesn't really prove  it does it? I was thinking to differentiate each of u and v, than equate the two ?

Comment: Of course, $f = g = c$! Another question, does the value of $c$ affect to the velocity field?

Comment: No I dot think it  it does.

Comment: Please, @italy, consider accepting the answer or let me know if you need any more help. I'll be happy to help.